# Is there a way to check the value of the cell to the left and add two to the count, unless there is a value entered in another cell in the same row?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, boolean, google-sheets-formula, worksheet-function

I am trying to write a piece of code in Google Sheets that automatically creates a follow-up date based on the date in the immediate left cell. It gets that date, and adds two (days) to it. Then that date gets pushed into Appsheet, where it is marked on a virtual calendar.

I also want the code to recognize when something is filled into the "Status" section (which is located in the 4th cell to the right) and fill in the current cell with something like "Done".

Currently, everything I have works except for that last part, when something is entered into the Status column I get an error that reads;

> Function IF parameter 1 expects boolean values. But 'Declined' is a
> text and cannot be coerced to a boolean.

I believe that means I need to convert the data in the status column into a boolean value, but I have no idea how to proceed in doing that. See below code;

```
=IF(INDIRECT("RC[4]",0), "Done", INDIRECT("RC[-1]",0) +2)
```

Let me know what you guys think, and thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("RC[4]",0)="Declined", "Done", INDIRECT("RC[-1]",0) +2)
```

or:

```
=IF(INDIRECT("RC[4]",0)<>"Declined", "Done", INDIRECT("RC[-1]",0) +2)
```

Comment: Is there a way to add other strings as well other than "Declined"? Like "Closed" and "Placed"?

Comment: @Nick try: `=IF(REGEXMATCH(INDIRECT("RC[4]",0), "Declined|Closed|Placed"), "Done", INDIRECT("RC[-1]",0) +2)`